# How to usort an ObjectArray in php?

Tags: php

Is there a way to usort an objectArray?  I only see a uasort method.  Thx for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ArrayObject::uasort — Sort the entries with a user-defined comparison function and maintain key association](http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.uasort.php)

Comment: thx for the reply.  I'm actually looking to sort the entries without maintaining key associations, which is why I posted that I was looking for usort and not uasort.  Cheers for trying though.

Comment: You could always tack on a `$array = array_values($array);`

Comment: Then uasort and copy the entries into another ArrayObject.